# Setting the height of UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios9

I have a label that is in a custom uitableview cell. I am using auto layout to position the label. My question is how can one set the height of the label to zero when it does not have any text. Or how to to make the label height 0. The project supports ios 8 so using stackview is out of the question. The label is also expansive i can't set a constant height constraint.My layout is given below .[image]

Comment: Just remove the height constraint and numberOfLines should be 0 so only top/leading/trailing constraint should be there.

Comment: There is no height constraint and the number of lines is zero. Actually the label calculates its size from its contents. But when the text is set to nil it will take the space for a one lined label.

Comment: if there are only 3 constraint like top/leading/trailing it will work double check may you have added bottom constraint ?

Comment: Yes it has four constraints . (content  label from screen shot) it has four constraints . leading, top, trailing and bottom to the view(transparent) that contain the search icons.

Comment: remove the bottom constraint of the `UILabel` will work fine for you, that's the reason one line is visible

Comment: try setting the height constraint of your label as 0 with Relation **Greater than or equal**.

Comment: I have actually diagnosed the problem . If i give a constant height for the result.pdf label every thing works fine but that label also has to be expansive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set label's height constraint >= 0. Label will update it's size to the content, and if text is missing height will be 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is possible that, set height constraint and take `outlet` of it and set it's `constant` to zero when text is nil.

Just ctrl + drag from height constraint to class to connect outlet to constraint.

then you can programatically change it's height when needed by changing it's constant.

for example,

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and change constant like,

```
 self.labelHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

In tableviewcell give height constraints except UILabel which one you need to hide.Change your Tableviewcell height it works.

[image]

For example, Your UILabel height is '30' and tableviewcell height is 130.You can give 130-30 = 100 in cell height.

```
//only sample code
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath.row == 0 
    return 130
else 
    return 100
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First set Height Constraint to Label. ctrl + drag the height Constraint to class to connect outlet to constraint. i.e

@IBOutlet weak var LabelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

and in implementation set the Height Constraint of Label to zero. As shown below....

```
self.LabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
if(check the label contains data)
{
    self.LabelHeightConstraint.constant = 20;
}
else
{
    self.LabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
}
```

This Logic will surely work......

Comment: That label is expansive .. so to make this thing work Ill need a way to dynamically calculate the size of the label

Comment: @Martin.. To make Label Expansive set Width Constraint to Label i.e.   self.LabelWidthConstraint.constant = 10 * count                                               where count is the length of text Label

Answer (score 0):

Set the text as nil as and when required and set the content hugging priority high